# Can VMware run on top of a OpenStack VM?

Tags: vmware, cloud, openstack

Our project has resources on an OpenStack cloud and needs to run an application that according to the application developers 'can only run on VMware' until a future release which will also run on OpenStack.

Is it possible to run VMware 'on top' of OpenStack so we get an environment that supports this application?

It might be inefficient but it would allow us to evaluate the application prior to them having an OpenStack implementation.

Answer (score 0):

VMWare is a supported hypervisor for OpenStack.

http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-compute/admin/content/vmware.html